# Eclipse Plugin for C++ with all functionality available for Java

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I recently installed the CDT plugin for C++ development in Eclipse. It provides useful features for building and debugging. However it does not have the following features available for Java:

1. Auto-complete of library functions or even user defined functions, variables etc.
2. Syntax checking as you type. For e.g., if I miss a ';' at end of line, it is not highlighted.

In short I'm looking for a plugin or someway to customize CDT to have the same support Eclipse provides for Java code.

Clarification - All the features I'm looking for are related to C++ code development.

Comment: "Works for me". In other words: CDT does exactly those things that you say it doesn't.

Comment: RE - lack of auto-complete:I believe that it does have auto-complete for library and user functions (I use it all the time) but the auto-completion behavior is different than for Eclipse-Java. |||| RE - as you type syntax highlighting: this feature is implemented in CDT but again behaves differently... as you type syntax checking is provided by the static code analysis Eclipse program "CODAN" but is only doing static code analysis (i.e. may miss some things or present false-positives)... many errors are only revealed when you compile (and likewise false-positives are revealed as false-positi).

Comment: I just realized your question is ambiguous. Do you want these features *for Java*, or do you want the feature that are already available for Java to be available *for C++*? I'm guessing the latter, since the question is tagged C++ but not Java, but the recently posted answer assumes the former. Please update your question to clarify that.

Comment: @Trevor - I only have as you type syntax highlighting out of the box with CDT. How do I get auto-complete and as you type syntax checking. Do I need to create a new project and add the files. I'm editing an existing *.cpp file developed elsewhere.

Comment: Sounds like you are somehow not using Eclipse-CDT correctly. ||||| Suffice to say these two features have been around in some form since about 2007 (when I started using Eclipse-CDT). In 2007 these two features were less featureful and did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

CDT comes only with C and C++ tools. You need to *also* install the Java tools, like this:

1. Choose: Help | Install New Software...
2. In the "Works with:" drop-down box, choose: --All Available Sites--
3. Select: Eclipse Java Development Tools

Comment: I *think* the OP is asking about feature for C++, but the question seems to be ambiguous.

Comment: It looks like this isn't what the OP is asking for.